# C++ in which way here is no l-value error?

Tags: c++

In which way it is possible to compile this code?

```
buf_right.el(j, k) = block.el(i, j, k);
```

Comment: What does the lhs statement returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the other answers, it is **not** necessary for `el` to return a reference, consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A& operator=(float f) {
    std::cout << "hey: " << f << std::endl;
  }
};

struct BR {
  A el(int j, int k) {
    return A();
  }
  float el(int i, int j, int k) {
    return 4.2;
  }
};

int main() {
  BR buf_right, block;
  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  buf_right.el(j, k) = block.el(i, j, k);
  return 0;
}
```

Running this prints the following to stdout:

> hey: 4.2

Comment: What if the values are of ordinary types, say `int`? Wondering if one can still overload `=` to achieve that?

Comment: @Hossein: To my knowledge no, it is not possible to implement e.g. `int& int::operator=(...)`. So in *that* case indeed you need a (mutable) reference.

Answer (score 6):

This is valid if the `el` method returns by reference. See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#returning-refs.

Comment: More precisely, if it returns *non-const* reference.

Comment: @Nawaz: Assuming that `operator=` isn't a const member function (which would be very very weird, but I think is legal).

Comment: @Nawaz: Yeah. There are actually a lot of ways it might not be valid -- I mean, the question doesn't even have anything to make it clear that `block.el(i, j, k)` has a return-type that's implicitly convertible to a type that `buf_right.el(j, k)`'s return-type has an accessible assignment operator for. Maybe I should have written, "This can be valid if ..." instead of "This is valid if ..."?

Answer (score 6):

if `buf_right.el(j, k)` returns a reference....

Similarly how the [] operator works, 
`a[2] =3` is equivalent to `a.operator[](2) = 3`